# A question about specific series that converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**Statement:** If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n^2 $ converges. Is this statement true or false. Also note that $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Question:** I have tried all the tests for a standard calculus course to prove this is true and cannot seem to get it. I have also tried finding some counterexamples, but I can't seem to do that either. Intuitively though I think its true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider $a_n=\begin{cases}(-1)^{n/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n/2}}&n\text{ even}, \\0&n\text{ odd}.\end{cases}$

Then $\sum a_n$ converges by the alternating series test ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{n/2}}$ is decreasing to zero.)

The sum $\sum (-1)^na_n^2$ is the the harmonic series (with extra zeroes), which diverges.

[Aside: strictly speaking, $a_n$ is not an alternating series, but the series $b_n=a_{2n}=(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is an alternating series and $\sum_{n=1}^ma_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}b_n$ and both sequences of partial sums converge together.]

Comment: @SalmonKiller The first few terms (for $a_n$) are (starting at $n=1$): $0$, $-1/\sqrt{1}$, $0$, $1/\sqrt{2}$, $0$, $-1/\sqrt{3}$, $0$, $1/\sqrt{4}$.  If you ignore the $0$ terms, you've got an alternating series.

Comment: @MichaelBurr OK. Another argument, alternating series are in the form $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ That is not the form in this case, even though it is very similar.

Comment: @SalmonKiller The partial sums of $\sum a_n$ equal the partial sums of an alternating series, so, although the series is not, strictly speaking alternating, the idea and the proof of the alternating series test can be applied without significant changes.

Comment: @SalmonKiller You can't make this work with a regular alternating series because $(-1)^na_n$ becomes alternating.  You need something else.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's exactly my point. For any alternating series in standard form this is true. However, your example is not an alternating series.

Comment: @SalmonKiller Note that you can split up the series into two separate summations, $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n n^{-1/2} + \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}0$.  The first summation converges by the AST, and the second converges to 0.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are so many comments here. This is a good example. One can use idea behind alternating series to conclude convergence. If one wants to be extremely rigorous, then you might prove an "alternating series test" where the odd indexed terms are zero and the even index terms alternate in sign. This is easy, as it *is* the alternating series proof in a shallow disguise. I've removed some of the comments here.